# Blank Universal Windows App - C++/CX returns exit code 1 (0x1)

Tags: c++, multithreading, uwp

In a Windows App I developed with Visual Studio I was having the following problem: When you close the window App with the X (Close the App) while debugging, some of the threads end with exit code 1 (0x1).

```
The thread 0x17bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x784 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3590 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7c4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x34d4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3328 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x164c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x2fb8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x2b50 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3c80 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x20cc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3520 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x359c has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x13bc has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x3cb4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1e74 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[15492] AppTest.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

After trying unsuccessfully to solve it, I tried to create a Blank App with Visual Studio 15 to see how everything was linked, to reproduce it, but the issue is happening also with the new created App. I didn't touch anything, just *New Project -> Build Blank App (UWP - C++/CX) -> Build & Run*, but still the same.

I thought that having an old version of VS could be the issue, so I downloaded VS19, repeated the process, and got surprised by the fact that it also happens in there.

Did anyone face a similar issue? Could it be my VS settings?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did this cause your app crash or did you receive any exception?

Comment: No, the app does fine. That happens when closing it "harshly" (closing the window). I realized now that when debugging the life cycles, when checking the shutdown it does the same, but instead, when stopping to debug, all threads exit with (0x0) code.

Comment: Currently, it won't have any impact, you don't have to concern it.

Comment: So, maybe I am wrong, and it is not related. But the main() function never reaches the end on that case, so some destructors are never called. Is it caused for something else? Thanks for the help.

Comment: When creating a blank app, can the main() function reach the end? If it can, maybe there is something wrong with the methods what you used in the main function.

Comment: No it doesn't. I am not sure if there is something really messed up with UWP/C++ or I am doing something wrong. For now I am doing a workaround and calling all the destructors by myself (which was my main issue) when the flag OnSuspending is triggered, although not the best.